# How to decode raw transaction?

Tags: javascript, taquito, encoding, signature

I am using @taquito to build and sign a transaction. But before I send it I want to decode it to check my destination address, amount etc like you would normally do for other blockchains.

Not sure how to do it, but I signed a request using my ED25519 signing key.
The signing was successful and the sbytes I got in return was

`008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46c008cb5baedee4dc3ec261dfcf57a9600bb0a8e26c0f00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d009595facf847a72b4c3fe231c0e4185e68e9b2875aa3c639382c86bcf0af23699f47fe66a6550ade936a5b59d5919ad20703885750314e0c368b277de39e7d10a`

I've read through some articles but could not find an exact way to do this and whatever I tried did not exactly yield what I wanted, which either means that I do not know how to decode the transaction, or my sbytes are wrong. Can anyone please explain on how do I decode this raw transaction using a Javascript/Typescript library to get stuff like

`fromAddress`
`toAddress`
`amount` etc. and if my signed transaction is correct. This is for testnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taquito can parse forged bytes using the `parse()` method in the `@taquito/local-forging` package.

TypeDocs are [here](https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_local_forging.localforger.html#parse). You can see the unit tests [here](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/master/packages/taquito-local-forging/test/taquito-local-forging.spec.ts#L565).

Implementation to decode a signed transaction:

```
const { localForger } = require('@taquito/local-forging');

const sbytes = '008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46c008cb5baedee4dc3ec261dfcf57a9600bb0a8e26c0f00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d009595facf847a72b4c3fe231c0e4185e68e9b2875aa3c639382c86bcf0af23699f47fe66a6550ade936a5b59d5919ad20703885750314e0c368b277de39e7d10a';

async function decode() {
    const unsignedPart = sbytes.substring(0, sbytes.length - 128); // Removing last 128 characters as that is the signature
    const decoded = await localForger.parse(unsignedPart);
    console.log(decoded);
}

decode();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `tezos-codec` binary to decode this:

```
tezos-codec decode 006-PsCARTHA.operation from 008f1d96e2783258ff663f03dacfe946c026a5d194c73d1987b3da73fadea7d46c008cb5baedee4dc3ec261dfcf57a9600bb0a8e26c0f00bdd85a0018452ac02e0a712000153957451d3cc83a71e26b65ea2391a1b16713d2d009595facf847a72b4c3fe231c0e4185e68e9b2875aa3c639382c86bcf0af23699f47fe66a6550ade936a5b59d5919ad20703885750314e0c368b277de39e7d10a
```

which yields

```
{ "branch": "BKiXcfN1ZTXnNNbTWSRArSWzVFc6om7radWq5mTqGX6rY4P2Uhe",
  "contents":
    [ { "kind": "transaction",
        "source": "tz1YU2zoyCkXPKEA4jknSpCpMs7yUndVNe3S", "fee": "1520",
        "counter": "2622173", "gas_limit": "10500", "storage_limit": "300",
        "amount": "300000",
        "destination": "tz2FwBnXhuXvPAUcr1aF3uX84Z6JELxrdYxD" } ],
  "signature":
    "sighZMqWz5G8drK1VTsmTnQBFEQ9kxQQxL88NFh8UaqDEJ3R3mzgR3g81azadZ9saPwsWga3kEPsyfbzrXm6ueuDvx3pQ5Q9" }
```

You can get more details about `tezos-codec` in its manual (`tezos-codec man -v 3`)

Comment: TOMASSSS you life saver. Any idea if there's an NPM library like tezos-codec?

Comment: I'm not sure what is its status, but you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nomadic-labs/tezos-codec

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RPC endpoint: `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/parse/operations` to do that.

Example:

```
await axios.post(
        `${nodeURL}/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/parse/operations`,
            parseOperationBytesData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        )
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit and show how `parseOperationBytesData` looks?

Comment: `parseOperationByteData` should be like `{"operations":[{"data":"6c00c800bfcc4fdca7ad8bfffa67f8378ab6bfe09d95a003bfb517f70b64a08d060000e02be16f594575ad492b7e991a1e2ee16af96eb4005c947f2ba2b1abbf04bf7785cf39322a5a7c24ae0e46da130bec9636ef018f61c9148e691dc58b8db96d9dd3d432a358ff63e81ac96ce7fee96ee5f3c7d3810e","branch":"BKrbEReHWBkJ8RDyhj59zJ6vjdCfJoVjMVQADLY6PspDEnCDXLs"}]}` where data is the raw transaction without the signature and without the first 64 characters (block_hash)